Advice for limited-mobility traveller from Czech Republic/Wien to Cyprus with "budget" airline
A friend is travelling from the Czech Republic (Brno area) to Cyprus and back. She is over 90 years old and has limited mobility. She walks with a simple, non-battery, wheeled zimmer frame which is quite compact and light. It folds into a rectangle of 20x80x50 cm3. She is slow walking but she can make it by herself.
I am looking for advice on whether budget flying (preferred due to cost) is a good idea for such a passenger. Candidates here are Ryanair, Easyjet, WizzAir from nearby airports of Katowice (Poland) or Wien (Austria) to Cyprus (all in EU). I am not saying or imagining that different airlines treat their reduced-mobility passengers differently. After all there must be some universal guidelines and minimum standards, at least within EU which is the case here.
The second question is whether this mobility equipment entails a charge and whether it is allowed in the cabin and how to notify the airline. I read from WizzAir that 2 pieces of mobility equipment are allowed free of charge and that they have their own in-cabin wheelchair (which it is prefered as it is designed for the geometry of the airplane). Is this strict? Are there going to be disputes whether the passenger is of reduced mobility? Does she need a paper from a doctor, in czech? Is it enough to turn with the zimmer frame at the check-in and they will pack it no-questions-asked?
The other option is Austrian Airlines. At a higher cost I can imagine.
You can assume that travelling from-to airports is all sorted out.

No experience with the airlines but my mother in like circumstances was given the advice to apply for help in each airport on her journey. No questions asked about whether she needed it.

Compare if a "budget" airline is more convenient. Because baggages and other items, possibly drink requirements, troubles with check-in requirements, printed tickets, ... We tend to overestimate saving on low-cost airlines (when not travelling light and targeted).
